# How to find out Time Complexity of python function

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have a function that loops through an array of items `a` and then will times them by `n`.
Its very basic.

```
a = [4,6,7,8,2,6,8,9]
n = 13

for i in range(len(a)):
    t = a[i] * n
    print(t)
```

How do I work out what the time complexity is? I'm new to this so detailed answers would be extremely helpful to help me learn.

Thank you

Comment: The time complexity of your algorithm is big `O(n)` because it repeats `n` number of times and then stops the execution.

Comment: AFAIK, that's the time complexity of a single for loop. Kindly enlighten us what is the correct answer that you believe. Thanks @superbrain

Comment: @RifatBinReza It is if n is the size of the loop. Here it's not, it's already defined as something else (`n = 13`). So the usual implicit assumption "n = size" doesn't apply.

Comment: @superbrain I'm sorry, but your argument is not sound here. We usually use `n` when it comes to big o notation. so regardless of what variable name is in that program, it shouldn't change the notation naming.

Comment: @RifatBinReza Nope, if n already means something else, then it means something else.

Comment: @superbrain This site relies on community involvement, so I would not expect every contributor to be contributing in a positive way.  All I can do is exemplify.  People will do whatever they feel like.

Comment: @superbrain I believe the point of the question was to let the OP know how to get the time complexity of his program and he mentioned he's new to this. The answer has the standard naming for n as the natural numbers. Now whatever the variable names are in the algorithm , doesn't change that. What if you have all the variable names in your program? Surely the name doesn't change the acceptance of the answer as a fact as that's not what's asked here

Comment: @RifatBinReza *Especially* when the OP is new to this, one should not mislead them by misusing names.

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity is `O{m}` where `m` is length of `a`.

You might be wondering why it is not `O{C * m}` where `C` is some constant coefficient?  In the term `C*m`, the contribution by `m` as `m` becomes larger will dwarf the contribution by `C` because `C` does not grow.  So, we replace the coefficient with `1`.

```
a = [4,6,7,8,2,6,8,9]
n = 13

for i in range(len(a)):  # scales with `m`
    t = a[i] * n         # `*` is atomic operation on modern processors
    print(t)             # constant operation
```

Comment: n is 13. Better don't reuse it for something entirely different.

Comment: @superbrain did you come in here and `-1` every answer?  It's not constructive.

Comment: Not sure how pointing out errors and getting them fixed isn't constructive. You forgot one, btw, in the code's comment.

Comment: Constructive is posting comments.  Posting a `-1` vote is trying to kill an answer.  That's not helping.

Comment: I find a wrong answer "not useful", and that's precisely what the downvoting is for.

Answer (score 0):

It will vary based on your implementation of loops.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  statement1;
  statement2;
}
```

Something like this will be O(4) which is pretty much the same as O(1).

If you have a variable of size n. When you loop over it, the size will be O(n).

For nested loops such as this one below it will be O(n^2).

```
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  statement1;

  for (let j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    statement2;
    statement3;
  }
}
```

It is well explained [here](https://adrianmejia.com/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm-code-big-o-notation/)

Answer (score -2):

It will be a simple O(n). The n comes from the loop which iterates n times. Inside the loop is nothing but O(1) operations.